# How to determine $A\in S_n (\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^5=I_n$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a symmetric real matrix $A\in S_n (\mathbb{R})$ and the polynomial $A^5-I_n=0$. The problem is that this ring is not an integral domain so I cannot factorize. The only thing I know is that $A$ in a special basis has coefficients on the diagonal but they have to be real.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $A=SDS^{-1}$ for a diagonal matrix $D=diag(d_1,\ldots ,d_n)$ and hence
$$
A^5=(SDS^{-1})^5=SD^5S^{-1}.
$$
hence $A^5=I$ says that $D^5=I$, i.e., $d_i^5=1$ for all $i$. Now you can solve this equation over the real numbers.

Comment: For real numbers the only possibility is $d_i= 1$ ?

Comment: Yes, because $(-1)^5=-1$. All  $5$-th roots of unity different from $1$ are not real.

Comment: So $A$ is $I_n$. Not interesting but thanks